# Huawei Push kit error code "907122036" no right :

Tags: java, android, push, huawei-mobile-services

when i try to get token for Huawei push kit, i logcat show errors like "no right", "service not available", "error code: 907122036". other apis working fine like map, timezone,

Answer (score 0):

> error code: 907122036

This error code indicates that Push Kit is not enabled.

please refer to [Getting Started](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137#section9471122085218) to check whether the related service is enabled for the app.

1. Sign in to AppGallery Connect and click **My projects**.
   [image]
2. Find and click the desired project in the project list, and click the app for which you need to set Push Kit parameters.
   [image]
3. Go to **Project settings** > **Manage APIs** and enable Push Kit.
   [image]
4. Go to **Grow** > **Push Kit** and click **Enable** now. In the dialog box that is displayed, click **OK**.
   [image]
5. Enable the precise messaging function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this error will come when you have forgotten to enable Push Kit from AGC.

For details, please refer to Getting Started to check whether the related service is enabled for the app.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137#section9471122085218

[image]

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/commonerror-0000001059816656

Before testing, you can also check for below preparations:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137

[image]